# Load function in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, permission-denied

I am relatively new to jquery and would like to know why the below code wouldn't work. I am trying to access the content from a file residing on my site and not outside. Is it because I have the jquery lib loading from google and not my site? The error message that I get in IE browser is "Access Denied". I am confused why the access is denied if I am trying to load a file from the same server and even same folder.

```
<html> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#response").load("http://www.mydomain.com/loadme.php?route=links/getlinks&path=2");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="response" style="border: 1px solid #000;height:500px;">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

any one please help me.

thanks

Comment: also, in ff sometime this works and some time it doesn't. I am not sure about IE.

Comment: what does firebug say is happening? http://getfirebug.com/ (Firefox Add-on)

Comment: What does loadme.php return? According to the manual `.load()` will not work if it returns `html`, `title` or `head` elements.

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: `language="JavaScript"` is not necessary - specifying the type is enough.

Comment: @jeroen, thanks but my code in loadme.php has only table and that has divs. Is this ok?

Comment: @user345579, it seems the problem is the `loadme.php` file, so you´d better post that as well.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but this link seems related. Some issue with Apache, and Firefox not sending a Content-Length header on a POST request. http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.ajax/browse_thread/thread/3b3d02927ec15c7ehttp://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.ajax/browse_thread/thread/3b3d02927ec15c7e

Comment: What URL is the page on?  `http://www.mydomain.com/page.php`, some other domain, subdomain? Please be very specific :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Code

```
$("#aboutme").click(function(){
    $("#response").load("/loadme.php?route=aboutme&path=2");
});
```

Html code
changed href ="javascript:void(0)"  to "#" . The problem in using this "#" is it will go to the top of the page each time when I click on a link. I removed href=# and it works fine but not sure if its ok not to have the href

```
<li>
    <a id="aboutme" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <span class="showcase-text">About Me</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: sorry to post after long time. I just noticed one main thing for this to work. my site url was without www but in the links in loadme.php I had www.sitename.com. This is the main issue. After I added the rewrite url in the .htaccess to make the site work either way (with/without www), everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you try

```
$.get('/loadme.php?route=links/getlinks&path=2', function(data) {
  $('#response').html(data);
});
```

at the very least you can

```
alert(data)
```

and see if that helps you debug.

Comment: H Jnunn, your suggestion worked for my test page but not in the place where I wanted to. I did as below in my answer and it works. the reason was I was having "javacript:void(o) in the links and when I changed it to #, it is fine except that the pages goes to the top and I guess I don't have a solution for that.